# Is the sign of a real number decidable?

Tags: logic, computability, provability, decidability

I'm working on the following problem in a class on provability.

> Consider how $\mathbb{R}$ might be presented. Is the property of being positive decidable?

How could the reals possibly be presented in such a way that this *isn't* decidable? Presumably the most natural presentation would be using a number's decimal expansion, but this doesn't get around the fact that we need to put in the $+$ or $-$ sign somehow. The algorithm "check whether the number is preceded by the $+$ sign" is certainly effective...

Can someone explain how I'm misinterpreting the question?

Comment: Usually a computational presentation of $\mathbb{R}$ is more along the lines of "increasingly accurate rational or decimal approximations to the number".  Now, if $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a recursive sequence of 1's and 0's, what's an equivalent condition to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 2^{-n} > 0$ (where the LHS can be approximated arbitrarily closely by calculating partial sums).

Comment: @DanielSchepler well as you've phrased it, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n2^{-n}$ is always $ \geq 0$, because each $a_n$ is either $0$ or $1$. Your "representation" has no negative numbers at all.

Comment: I'm interpreting your "positive" as "strictly positive".  If you're interpreting it as "0 or strictly positive" then switch to determining whether $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 2^{-n} \ge 0$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm not sure I understand. The decimal expansion of whatever real number we're considering seems largely irrelevant. The only thing that matters is the sign on the first digit.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n 2^{-n} > 0$ is equivalent to $\exists n, a_n = 1$.  So, if you could decide whether this number is (strictly) positive, then you could decide for any recursive subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ whether $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}, n \in S$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite know if I've understood the question, but I think that for all possible presentations of $\mathbb{R}$, it's not computable. Indeed, there are two ways to interpret your question, and neither is computable.

- Suppose we could compute whether $x \geq 0$. Then we could compute whether $x = 0$ by determining whether both $x \geq 0$ and $-x \geq 0$. But that's uncomputable. So we can't compute whether $x \geq 0$.
- Suppose we could determine whether $x > 0$. Then we could compute whether $x = 0$ by determining whether $x > 0$ and $-x > 0$ are both false.

For a specific example, take a presentation of machines which spit out first a sign, then a digit every time-step, with exactly one decimal point at some time. The problem you have here is that you can't convert zero to a canonical form of $+0$. That is, if you've got a Turing machine which outputs $-0.00000\dots$, you can't tell whether that machine is representing $0$ or not.

Comment: This presentation would also have a disadvantage that you couldn't compute sums (e.g. if you sum $0.90909090\ldots$ and $0.09090909\ldots$, you don't know whether to output $1.00000000\ldots$ or $0.99999999\ldots$ because any change at the 100th digit in either input could change it in favor of one or the other).  Which you typically fix by allowing a slightly larger amount of "revision" in each step...  But undecidability of being equal to 0 (or equivalently, undecidability of being positive) is a fundamental issue.

Comment: I agree that your Turing machine would not be able to decide whether $x = 0$. Is the property $x \geq 0$ decidable then? Assuming that our presentation is a decimal expansion?

Comment: @Alex The example also illustrates why $x \ge 0$ is undecidable: if you have $-0.000000$ so far, should you return true or false?  You don't know: the eventual number could be $-0.000000121109\ldots$ or it could be $-0.000000000000\ldots$.